# Output string as currency format in excel by POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to output "2655.32" as "$2,655.32" in excel.

Here is code snippet:

```
case 0:
    HSSFCellStyle style;
    style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    style.setDataFormat((short) 7);
    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("2655.32"));
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
break;
```

The generated excel cell doesn't show "$" or thousand comma ",", and there is an error check warning, **"The number in this cell is formated as text or preceded by an apostrophe**. I can get what I want by double clicking the cell to let excel fix it, the "$" and "," will show up.

I know I can use  `cell.setCellValue(Double.parse("2655.32"))`  to parse the string to a double to solve this, but if so, I have to make sure the value is parseable and add try catch block to each of my switch case, which is very duplicate.

I am wondering if there is a way to output this kind numeric string as text and keep the currency format at the same time? like this $2,655.32

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/poi/setDataFormat.shtml) is a nice tutorial of solving your problem. `HSSFDataFormat` has some built in formats. Using the format `#,##0.0` should solve your problem, like bellow:

```
 HSSFCellStyle cs = hssfworkbook.createCellStyle();
 HSSFDataFormat df = hssfworkbook.createDataFormat();
 cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.0")); //or cs.setDataFormat((short)7);
 cell.setCellValue(2655.32);
 cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.setCellValue(416.17);      
cellStyle.setDataFormat((short)7);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```